# Differentiating between clicked links?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to HTML/CSS/JS etc. and am just creating a little prototype page as a hobby.

I've gotten stuck attempting to reuse a particular bit of javascipt, as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function noDownload()
{
document.getElementById("nodownload").innerHTML="Download unavailable.";
}
</script>
```

Then further down the page I'll have the following:

```
<h3>r9 (Mar 23, 2013) <a id="nodownload" onClick="noDownload()"><img id="nodownload" height="19" width="19" src="[imagerurl]"></a></h3>
```

And then it will be displayed a few more times...

```
<h3>r7 (Jan 11, 2013) <a id="nodownload" onClick="noDownload()"><img id="nodownload" height="19" width="19" src="[imageurl]"></a></h3>
```

If I click on the r9 image, I get the result I want - the image is replaced with the text 'Download unavailable.'

If however I click the r7 image, then it's the r9 image that is replaced by the text, not the r7 image.

Any solutions?

Comment: You should separate your javascript into a separate file and maybe look into using jQuery for your JavaScript page manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Id's should always be unique** - use unique ID's instead or give them both a common class.

Here I'm giving them each a unique ID:

```
<h3>r1 (Jan 7, 2013) <a id="noDownloadOne" onClick="noDownload('aOne')"><img height="19" width="19" src="http://i.imgur.com/In5SIVc.png">a</a></h3>
<h3>r2 (Jan 7, 2013) <a id="noDownloadTwo" onClick="noDownload('aTwo')"><img height="19" width="19" src="http://i.imgur.com/In5SIVc.png">a</a></h3>
```

Then depending on which is selected, change the innerHTML accordingly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function noDownload(e) {
    if(e == 'aOne') {
      document.getElementById("noDownloadOne").innerHTML="Download unavailable One.";
        alert('aOne was chosen');
    }
    else if(e == 'aTwo') {
      document.getElementById("noDownloadTwo").innerHTML="Download unavailable Two.";
        alert('aTwo was chosen');
    }
    else {
        alert('Neither aOne nor aTwo was chosen');
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is a working jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ezauy/2/

Comment: Just tried this and it results in only 'nodownloadTwo' changing, regardless of which image I click.

Comment: @user2205192 Can you make a jsFiddle with all your html/javascript as it should do

Comment: Never heard of jsFiddle - just had a look and the formatting confuses me. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @user2205192 Great to hear! feel free to 'tick' my answer/upvote if it works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML ID's are supposed to be unique on a page, so I'm guessing if there's more than one it will only ever select the first element with that matching ID.  If you want to reuse it then instead you can use `class="nodownload"` instead of `id="nodownload"`.

Comment: Using a class will cause ALL the images to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use same Id for two different elements

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don't need to use id's at all for your code to work. You can pass a reference to the element that was clicked in your handler. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleClick(target) {
        console.log(target); // for debugging
        target.innerHTML='clicked';
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="handleClick(this)">click me</a>
```

EDIT: It turns out it's been so long since I connected an anchor to a function this way that I didn't get it quite right. I have fixed it now.

Comment: As a general debugging technique, you will be making friends with your console. In this case, adding a line `console.log(this)` in the function will be the first step to seeing where it's going wrong.

Comment: I'm viewing the HTML in Chrome and although I've got it outputting to the console it's... confusing. There's a lot of info. How can I narrow down the issue?

Comment: This is tricky to answer without looking over your shoulder, but as you dive into this, you will need to answer a series of questions: 1) Is the function being called? An alert box will answer that. 2) Are the values what I expect them to be? This is where logging to the console comes in. (This is not the same pane that shows the html for the entire page.) The first thing to know about `this` is what type of DOM element it is. The console will show a snippet of HTML, and the outermost tag is what's interesting.

Comment: 1) There's nothing in the console until I click on one of the images that calls the function, then a line of something or another appears with a dropdown arrow. Click the dropdown and there's more than I can begin to understand. 2) No idea... || I've found the function noDownload in the dropdown, what do I look at now?

Comment: Function is being called, that's good. In that html gobbledygook you see, what's the very first html tag?

Comment: I don't know, here's a screenshot of what I'm looking at: http://i.imgur.com/wSPeGK4.png